# Circuit Analysis Question

Tags: circuit-analysis

**For the circuit given in Figure Q6, calculate the total current and power of
the voltage supply, and the voltages V1 and V2. All resistors are of 1 kΩ**

[image]

I have tried applying the Kirchhoff's law like this.

[image]

But i couldn't get to answer. I found the Voltage Drop between V1 1,6 Volts but i couldn't find V2.

Thanks

Comment: Why not V2?....?

Comment: I couldn't understand what to write on - side of the V2 as it is not a closed loop. I know + side is 10V but i don't know how to find the negative terminal

Comment: V2- = 1/2 of V1- side, V2+=10V because the series 1k+1k draw no current.

Comment: This would be easier if you named your resistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is school work, direct answers are strongly discouraged.  Here is some guidance to "see" the problem more clearly.

1. Assign reference designators to each component.  Assign a GND symbol to the 10 V negative node.
2. Anywhere there are two or more resistors in series *without any connections to the joining nodes*, combine them.
3. Anywhere there are two or more resistors in direct parallel, combine them.
4. Redraw the schematic so all resistors are either vertical or horizontal.  See the way the two resistors connected to GND are spaced apart for clarity?  Do that for the +10 V node.
5. Now the current paths should be easier to see and discuss.